# Virtual Ubuntu Network Configuration

Tags: configuration, virtualization, networking, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu as main OS. I have created virtual Ubuntu in Sun VirtualBox and I get this error: `can not connect(ssh)/ping computers in local network`.  If I configure network manually I even can not access to Internet. If I choose DHSP then I can access to Internet. Do you have some solution how to connect computers in local network from virtual Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting your network connection type to Bridged will give your virtual machine its own IP address on your network, where it will be able to see any of the other machines, including the VM host.

Answer (score 1):

I used NAT in Sun VirtualBox network configuration. When I choose Bridge it worked...